# Regex for string matching ****${****}***

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to write a regex that matches and excludes all strings in a file that contain `${` followed by `}` with any characters between or around it. In between could be any characters/numbers/underscores/dashes/etc (there won't be another parenthesis inside).

Example matches:

```
hello ${VAR}
${HELLO_VAR} world
https://${WEB_VAR}
```

I came up with this: `egrep -v '^\${[a-zA-Z?]'`, though it seems to be working partially and I am not too sure if its right. How can I do this?

The input file has strings separated by a newline, very similar to simple java properties.

Comment: How do you split the strings in your file? By newlines, blanks, punctuation? Because you know a text file is essentially just one large string.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that you're looking for a regex you'll use to exclude lines from a file, or are you saying that you want to strip the matched parts from the file, leaving the rest of the lines that contain matches to the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give this one a shot:

```
\$\{[^}]*\}
```

Match `${` literally, followed by everything except `}`, followed by `}`

Answer (score 3):

You can trying using sed command.

```
sed 's/\$\{[^}]*\}//g' <input_file> > <output_file>
```

Sed here excludes all the characters between '{' and '}' and writes the new content in a new output file.

Comment: You could leave the `cat` out and use `<input_file>` as a `sed` argument instead ;)

Comment: Doing this with `.*` will match `...${foo}...${bar}...` as having `foo}...${bar` as a single string inside the match group -- so using this will remove everything from the very first expression in line within the input file to the very last expression in that line, not only the contents of the individual/distinct expressions. There's a (good) reason why philipp's answer uses `[^}]*` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I saw his answer. But in the question it was written that there are no parentheses inside so I didn't focus on it.

Comment: @Sharath, you miss my point -- `${foo}something else ${bar}` will be treated by this regex as `foo}something else ${bar` being the contents of a single match. Indeed, there *are* no nested curly brackets inside `${foo}`, but your regex doesn't know to stop at the `}` after `foo` and instead goes on to the very last `}` in the line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the explanation, I get it now. Editing my answer to include philipp's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You say you're trying to *exclude all strings in a file*, so it sounds like you need something a bit more advanced than just a regex with `grep`.  I'd do this with an awk script:

```
awk '{while(match($0,/\$\{[^}]*\}/)){$0=substr($0,0,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}} 1' input.txt
```

Or, split for easier reading and commenting:

```
{
  while (match($0,/\$\{[^}]*\}/)) {
    $0=substr($0,0,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
1
```

The idea here is that for each line, we'll check to see whether the regex matches anything on the line. If it does, we'll replace the line with the parts *around* the matched regex. (We could alternate `sub(/RE/,"")`, but that would require applying the regex twice per match rather than once.)

The final `1` is shorthand that says "print the current line". It runs whether or not the loop processed any matches.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the global wilcard `.*` around the two sequences, as in:

```
.*\$\{.*\}.*
```

As you want to match entire lines, you have to use wilcard at both sides, to extend the regexp to both ends (it doesn't matter if you anchor it with `^` and `$` as the greedy algorithm will try to extend as much as possible)  Note that the `$`, `{` and `}` must be escaped, as they are reserved by the regexp language.

This can be seen in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/cNYDrn/1).

## note

the title of this question doesn't specify that the substring between the two curly braces should not have a `}`, and as you want only to match the whole line, then it is not necessary to check for something except a `}`, the only requirement is that `}` must be after the `${` in the line.  Anyway, this has no drawback in efficiency, as the NFA that parses this regexp has the same number of states as the other.